# Comparing variable to itself in case_when() under group_modify()

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following kind of data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

data <- tibble(a = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3),
               b = c('x', 'y', 'z', 'z', 'z'),
               c = c('ps', 'ps', 'qs', 'rs', 'rs'),
               d = c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500),
               strt = ymd(c('2019-03-20', '2020-01-01', '2018-01-02', '2020-05-01', '2016-01-01')),
               fnsh = ymd(c(NA, NA, NA, '2020-06-01', '2016-05-01')))
```

I need to find the rows with starts within the latest year for all groups as defined by a, b, c (i.e. `data %>% group_by(a, b, c)`). A row has a start within the latest year if:

1) The date qualifies: strt is within the latest year

2) There are no overlaps: No rows in the group have a strt before and a fnsh later (or fnsh as NA)

In the following, STRT should refer to strt from the highest level in the grouped operation. That is, STRT is supposed to point to the instance of .x outside
 `filter()`.

```
test <- data %>%
  group_by(a, b, c) %>%
  group_modify(function(.x, .y) {
               .x %>%
               mutate(startLatestYear = case_when(strt > today(tzone = 'CET') - years(1) &
                                                  strt <= today(tzone = 'CET') &
                                                  nrow(filter(.x, strt < STRT &
                                                                  fnsh %in% NA |
                                                                  fnsh >= STRT)) == 0 ~ 1,
                                                  TRUE ~ 0))}) %>%
  ungroup()
```

How can I construct STRT?

Comment: You say `no rows in the group have a sort before and a fsnh later.` What does `group` mean here?

Comment: I have edited the post to clarify the meaning of group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there are no answers by now, I think it is fair to post alternative approaches to completing the task. The following completes the task without solving the problem (i.e. STRT is *not* constructed).

```
test <- data %>%
  mutate(pushInterval = interval(strt + days(1), fnsh)) %>%
  group_by(a, b, c) %>%
  group_modify(function(.x, .y) {
               .x %>%
               mutate(startLatestYear = case_when(strt > today(tzone = 'CET') - years(1) &
                                                  strt <= today(tzone = 'CET') &
                                                  !strt %within% .x$pushInterval ~ 1,
                                                  TRUE ~ 0))}) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Turns out that the above does not work as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Is creating the variable `STRT` before the `group_modify()` what you are looking for?

```
data %>%
  group_by(a, b, c) %>%
  mutate(STRT = max(strt)) %>% 
  group_modify(function(.x, .y) {
    .x %>%
      mutate(startLatestYear = case_when(strt > today(tzone = 'CET') - years(1) &
                                           strt <= today(tzone = 'CET') &
                                           nrow(filter(.x, strt < STRT & (fnsh %in% NA | fnsh >= STRT))) == 0 ~ 1,
                                         TRUE ~ 0))})
```

Basically, for each group composed by `a, b, c`, you construct `STRT` that is the latest date for that specific group.

Output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 8
# Groups:   a, b, c [4]
#       a b     c         d strt       fnsh       STRT       startLatestYear
#   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <date>     <date>     <date>               <dbl>
# 1     1 x     ps      100 2019-03-20 NA         2019-03-20               0
# 2     1 y     ps      200 2020-01-01 NA         2020-01-01               1
# 3     2 z     qs      300 2018-01-02 NA         2018-01-02               0
# 4     3 z     rs      400 2020-05-01 2020-06-01 2020-05-01               1
# 5     3 z     rs      500 2016-01-01 2016-05-01 2020-05-01               0
```

Comment: Nope. Put roughly, I need STRT to be the same as strt from the two conditions above and outside ```nrow(filter(.x,...``` in ```case_when()```. However, it has to be comparible to strt within ```nrow(filter(.x,...```. That is what leads to the problem with referencing. It should give us ```startLatestYear = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0)```.

Comment: Thinking about your rationale on constructing `STRT`, I realized that you are probably missing some parentheses for condition number 2. Which is, statements `fnsh %in% NA` and `fnsh >= STRT`, separated by "or" `|`, should be enclosed within brackets, otherwise the `&` operator will be performed before the `|` operator. I modified the answer and now it gives the expected output.

Comment: Correct regarding the brackets.

Comment: STRT should not be the latest start in every group. STRT should refer to the first instance of strt in the grouped operation (i.e. strt as it appears in ```strt > today(tzone = 'CET') - years(1) & strt <= today(tzone = 'CET')```.

Comment: I think I understood what you are looking for, but I'm afraid I cannot help.. I suggest you to start a bounty on your question if you are really looking for a correct answer.